# How to sum up values in Solr4.10.3

Tags: sql, solr, sum, cloudera, facet

I installed Solr from CDH which version is  4.10.3-cdh5.13.0.
My job like one sql work like,How to realize by Solr4:

```
select D,E,sum(A),sum(B) from DOC where C='balabala' group by D , E;
```

I try this one,but only one column in group section.

```
&stats=on
&stats.field=A
&stats.field=B
&stats.facet=D
```

In Solr5,code below works,but in Solr4 failed:

```
facet=true&stats=true&stats.field={!tag=piv1}A&facet.pivot={!stats=piv1}D,E
```

Is there one approach ?
and one more question: 
how to realize

```
select D,E,sum(A*B) from DOC where C='balabala' group by D , E;
```

Comment: You are on Cloudera Search right ? What do you mean by `sum(A)`, `sum(B)` & `sum(A*B)` ? Are A and B multivalued fields ?

Comment: `group by D and E`? In SQL you'd do `group by D, E`.

Comment: @EricLavault, i.e  A is price ,B is count, single value field.